# Haskell: Dynamic object field name with aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

If I have a data structure that takes in two values from `readFile`; how do I use those values as the fieldnames for my `toJSON` instance declaration?

For example in the code below, the names "2015" and "2016" are to change depending on the input file.

```
data MyOutput = MyOutput
              { periodOne   :: YearInfo
              , periodTwo   :: YearInfo
              , updateStamp :: String
              } deriving (Show)

instance ToJSON MyOutput where
  toJSON MyOutput {..} =
    object [ "2015"       .= periodOne
           , "2016"       .= periodTwo
           , "Data up to" .= updateStamp
           ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `ToJSON` instances cannot depend on values external to the data structure.

My suggestion is to change the data structure to include the field names for `periodOne` and `periodTwo`:

```
data MyOutput = MyOutput {
                  periodOneName, periodTwoName :: String,
                  periodOne, periodTwo :: YearInfo
                  ...
              }
```

Now the `toJSON` instance has access to the names of the periods.

Complete example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.Text as T

type YearInfo = [ Int ]

data MyOutput = MyOutput
              { periodOne   :: YearInfo
              , periodTwo   :: YearInfo
              , periodOneName :: T.Text
              , periodTwoName :: T.Text
              , updateStamp :: String
              } deriving (Show)

instance ToJSON MyOutput where
  toJSON MyOutput {..} =
    object [ periodOneName .= toJSON periodOne
           , periodTwoName .= toJSON periodTwo
           , "Data up to"  .= toJSON updateStamp
           ]
```

Comment: would you be so kind as to write out the ToJson instance.